# Selecting specific rows from CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have the following rows in a csv file

```
import csv

with open('testfile.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    filewriter.writerow(['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'])
    filewriter.writerow(['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4'])
    filewriter.writerow([6.1, 5.0, 3, 420])
    filewriter.writerow([6.2, 5.9, 2, 520])
    filewriter.writerow([6.5, 5.4, 1, 320])
```

My goal is to remove the duplicated row and only select rows where var3 != 1. However, unexpected results are returned.

```
with open('testfile.csv', 'rb') as infile, open('testfile_clean.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    infile.next()
    for row in infile:
        if row[2] != '1':
            outfile.write(row)
```

testfile_clean.csv contains the following row:

```
var1,var2,var3,var4
6.2,5.9,2,520
6.5,5.4,1,320
```

It got rid of the first row with the values, instead of basing it on whether var3 <> '1'. Any thoughts on what might be happening would be appreciated!

Comment: No idea if it's related to the problem, but is it your intention to write the header row twice?

Answer (score 2):

Using python's default file reading, will give you each line as a separate string, so one line would be "6.1,5.0,3,420". In the code you posted, row was that string, so row[2] would be its third character, or "1" in the case of this line, hence your code ignored this line. Classic examples of where the untyped beauty of python can come back to bite you!

The solution? You're going to want to open the file with csv.reader, which automatically splits the line by commas, so that the line "6.1,5.0,3,420" will be ["6.1","5.0","3","420"]. Here's the code that'll do that:

```
import csv

with open('testfile.csv', 'rb') as infile, open('testfile_clean.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        if row[2] != '1':
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

While writing to csv file you are using `writerow`, which can write list for each entry. In order to read the same data, you need to use `reader` which can iterare over each line and your entry will be treated as a list.

```
import csv

with open('testfile.csv', 'r') as infile, open('testfile_clean.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    rows = csv.reader(infile)
    next(rows)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    for row in rows:
        print(row)
        if row[2] != '1':
            writer.writerow(row)
```